# Best way to establish a connection for use with an ADO.NET command object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I'm designing a web service in ASP.NET and VS2008, and am using typed datasets for retrieving table data. These work well and establish their own connections through their associated TableAdapter objects. Edit: I'm using VB, BTW!

I am now attempting to run a custom SQL string using a DataAdapter and a Command object, however I need to reference a Connection object in order for the Command to work. What is the best way to handle this? Should I:

a) Create a global connection object using Global.asax, retrieving the connection string from web.config? (I've been trying that one already, with not much success)

b) Create a class-level connection object using the InitialiseComponent method, also retrieving the ConnectionString from web.config?

c) Retrieve a Connection from one of the TableAdapters that I've already created in my typed DataSets?

d) Something else I haven't thought of yet?

BTW I've been finding it very difficult to extract a ConnectionString from web.config, so any help with that would be appreciated also!

I'm not entirely inexperienced with ASP.NET, but my last big project used VS2003, and I want to make sure that I'm using the current tools correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the connection string, use

```
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString
```

It's best to open and close the connections as close as possible to their use. ADO.NET will do connection pooling so that this won't be expensive:

```
var connectionString = 
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("query", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Use the command
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for that bit of advice - I was wondering whether a global connections were more efficient or not. I forgot to mention that I'm using VB, however I think I can translate!

Answer (score 1):

For Connection and data access problems I will advise you to go with some kind of Data Helpers like [Microsoft Data Access Application Block](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f63d1f0a-9877-4a7b-88ec-0426b48df275&displaylang=en)

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510013046/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070203-1.aspx) you can find small tutorial about how to use it.

For getting connectionstring from web.config use folowing methods

```
 public static string GetConnectionString( string strConstringKey )
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[strConstringKey];
        }

        public static bool GetConnectionString(string strConstringKey, ref string strConstring)
        {
            return (strConstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[strConstringKey] ) == null ? false : true  ;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks - your syntax for retrieving the connection string turned to be the one that worked. Up-voted it, since I can't accept two answers!

Comment: Also, I'm checking out the links you provided - forgot to mention that.

Comment: Had a look at Data Access Application Block - great idea, will save a lot of coding! Thanks for the link.